# Calculate third point of Isosceles triangle given two points and angle

Tags: geometry, vectors, triangles

In this image: (Just for annotations.. The actual triangle can be pointing to any direction)

[image: isosceles triangle]

I know the coordinates of "red" base points and the "blue" vertex angle $\beta$, and I want to calculate the coordinates of the "blue" vertex point.

I did come up with a solution but it looks unnecessarily complex so I'm hoping there is an easier solution..

What I did was, using the Law of sines, I got $\frac{a}{sin \alpha} = \frac{b}{sin \beta}$ and since $sin \frac{\beta}{2} = \frac{b}{2a}$, I have $sin \beta = 2sin \frac{\beta}{2} cos\frac{\beta}{2} = \frac{bL}{a^2}$ (Eq. 1)

From Pythagoras' Theorem I have $L^2 + \frac{b^2}{4} = a^2$, I rewrite Eq. 1 as $sin \beta = \frac{bL}{(\frac{b^2}{4} + L^2)}$ which then gives me a quadratic equation in terms of L.. Then finding the positive root of this equation, I can calculate the normal vector along L and find the position of peak point.. But I'm hoping there is an easier way for it :)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think writing the equation of the perpendicular bisector and then using the parametric form of a line may help.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking of.. I will calculate the direction of L and go from the center point towards that direction..

Comment: If your base points are arbitrary (do not have the same $y$) I recommend you consider complex numbers solution. $z_3-z_1=(z_2-z_1) \frac{a}{b} \exp(i\alpha)$, $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{1}{2\sin(\beta/2)}$, $\alpha=\frac{\pi-\beta}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Addendum added to respond to the comment of wololoo.

---

$\displaystyle \alpha = \frac{180 - \beta}{2}.$

$L = a \times \sin(\alpha).$

Therefore, the problem reduces to finding $~\displaystyle \frac{b}{2}$, which is immediate, by the [Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).

$b^2 = 2a^2 - 2a^2\cos(\beta).$

**Edit**
Alternatively, $~\displaystyle \frac{b}{2} = a\cos(\alpha).$

---

**Addendum**
Responding to the comment of wololoo.

> ...then what do you mean by the phrase location of the upper point?

> The illustration is just one i found on Google, the actual triangle does not have to be "upright", the points' y coordinates can be different. I want a general solution to find the coordinates of the "peak" point.

Under the assumption that the base of the triangle makes an angle of $(0^\circ)$ with the horizontal, then (as stated) the Cartesian coordinates of the upper vertex are $~\displaystyle \left[a\cos(\alpha), a\sin(\alpha)\right].~$ Here, it is understood that $~\displaystyle \frac{b}{2} = a\cos(\alpha), ~L = a\sin(\alpha).$

In effect you are questioning my assumption that the base of the triangle makes an angle of $(0^\circ)$ with the horizontal, and asking what the effects would be if the base of the triangle was rotated $(\theta)^\circ$ (counter-clockwise).

The effect would be that each point on the triangle would be similarly rotated.  To visualize this, see the diagram to the right in [this section of wikipedia trig identies : angle sum identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities).

To actually determine the resulting Cartesian coordinates, the easiest approach is to **go back and forth** between polar coordinates and Cartesian coordinates.

Assuming that the base of the triangle makes an angle of $(0^\circ)$ with the horizontal, the polar coordinates of the vertex are simply $(a,\alpha)$, where $a$ is the magnitude of the distance, and $\alpha$ is the angle that the line segment makes with the horizontal.

The polar coordinates of $(a,\alpha)$ are equivalent to the Cartesian coordinates of $[ ~a\cos(\theta), a\sin(\theta) ~].$

Under the assumption that the base of the triangle (instead) makes an angle of $(\theta)$ with the horizontal, you have that the **adjusted** polar coordinates of the vertex are simply $(a,\alpha + \theta).$  These adjusted polar coordinates translate to adjusted Cartesian coordinates of

$$[ ~a\cos(\alpha + \theta), a\sin(\alpha + \theta) ~]. \tag1 $$

It is unclear to me whether (1) above is the type of expression that you are looking for.  You can remove all reference to $\alpha$ in (1) above, replacing it with $~\displaystyle \frac{b}{2}$ and $L$.  However, I question the logic of that, because the magnitudes of $~\displaystyle \frac{b}{2}$ and $L$ were themselves computed via the cosine and sine functions applied against the angle $\alpha$.

Anyway, if that is your wish, you can use that

- $\cos(\alpha + \theta) = \cos(\alpha)\cos(\theta) - \sin(\alpha)\sin(\theta).$
- $\sin(\alpha + \theta) = \sin(\alpha)\cos(\theta) + \cos(\alpha)\sin(\theta).$

Then, using the above identies, you can replace $a\cos(\theta)$ with $~\displaystyle \frac{b}{2}~$ and replace $a\sin(\alpha)$ with $L$.  This allows the expression in (1) above to be equivalently expressed as

$$\left[ ~\frac{b}{2}\cos(\theta) - L\sin(\theta), ~L\cos(\theta) + \frac{b}{2}\sin(\theta) ~\right].$$

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I already know the locations of two points, so I already know $b$.. I need the location of the upper point.

Comment: @wololoo I am unsure that I know what you are asking.  Assuming that the Cartesian coordinate of the lower left vertex is arbitrarily designated as $(0,0)$, and the lower right vertex is designated as $(b,0)$, then the Cartestian coordinate of the upper vertex is $~\displaystyle \left(\frac{b}{2}, L\right)$.  This is why I provided the explicit formulas for calculating $(L)$ and $(b)$.  If this does not answer your question, then what do you mean by the phrase *location of the upper point*?

Comment: The illustration is just one i found on Google, the actual triangle does not have to be "upright", the points' y coordinates can be different. I want a general solution to find the coordinates of the "peak" point.

Comment: @wololoo It is still unclear to me what you are asking.  I have added an Addendum to the end of my answer to try to anticipate and respond to the question that you **might** be asking.  If this does not answer your question, then I will need you to be much more explicit about what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

The bisector $L$ divides the isosceles triangle into two right triangles.
From one of those right triangles,

$$ \frac b2 = L \tan\frac\beta2, $$
so
$$ L = \frac b2 \cot\frac\beta2. $$